# Set ANOVA contrast in Python OLS

Tags: python, anova

Is there a way to define the contrast of the ANOVA on Python using the **OLS.fit()** function?
Trying to extend the R code `Contrast("Contr.sum", "Contr.sum")` to Python without success.

```
Results=ols('score ~ C(Var3) + C(Var1) + C(Var2)', data=Dataset).fit()
```